# Django: Adding a field which allows multiple images

Tags: django, django-forms

## Forms.py

```
class SellerForm(forms.ModelForm):
username = forms.CharField()
class Meta:
model = Seller
fields = [
'username',
'first_name',
'last_name',
'country',
'image_of_seller',
'city',
'date_of_birth',
'describe_yourself'
]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].initial = self.instance.seller.username
    
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, commit=True):
        seller = super().save(commit=False)
        user = seller.seller
        self.instance.seller.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    
        if commit:
            seller.save()
            user.save()
    
        return seller
```

## Views.py

```
class SellerUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = Seller
form_class = SellerForm
template_name = 'core/seller_update_form.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user.seller
```

## Models.py

```
class Seller(models.Model):
seller = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=False)
country = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
identification = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
image_of_seller =  models.ImageField(null=False, blank=True) # I want this to accept multiple files, which are images.
city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
describe_yourself = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.seller.username
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.seller.username)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know I can create another model, with a ForeignKey to the Seller model, then have inline while creating ModelAdmin. But is there a way to have this for the form instead? I want the user to be able to update their pictures.

## Update

I am thinking of something that behaves like StackedInline, like the example below. But instead rendering it not in admin, but instead in the SellerForm.

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    #changed from seller to user, just for readability. 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    identification = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    describe_yourself = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, blank = True)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def calculate_age(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        year = today.strftime("%Y")
        current_year = int(year)
        user_year = int(self.date_of_birth.year)
        age = current_year - user_year
        self.age = age 
        return age
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.seller.username
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.calculate_age
        self.slug = slugify(self.seller.username)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class ImageOfSeller(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Image = models.ImageField()

# Admin.py 


class ImageSellerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ImageOfSeller 
    can_delete = True 
    verbose_name_plural = 'seller_image'
    extra = 0

class SellerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ImageSellerInline,
    ]
admin.site.register(Seller, SellerAdmin)
```

Comment: what is the question here? you want to do that in the same model with one field? or how can you do it with another image model and forms?

Comment: I want the SellerForm to allow one field, which allows for multiple picture uploads. In the SellerForm I can add a ImageField, but this allows only one picture. I am wondering if there is a way to store multiple images. I know I can create another model with a ForeignKey to the Seller, where it has an ImageField, then use StackedInline for that model, which allows me to add multiple images. This creates what I want, a way for me to add multiple images. But I want that functionality inside the SellerForm.

Comment: i gave you an answer about arrayfields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **I found a another solution everyone.**

First I created my own field instead, which allows me to upload multiple files. [MultipleFileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files).

```
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput, FileField 

class MultipleFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    allow_multiple_selected = True

class MultipleFileField(FileField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("widget", MultipleFileInput())
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, data, initial=None):
        single_file_clean = super().clean
        if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
            result = [single_file_clean(d, initial) for d in data]
        else:
            result = single_file_clean(data, initial)
        return result
```

Then I added `validate_image_file_extension` which validates if the image is an actual image. [validate_image_file_extension](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/validators/#validate-image-file-extension), where I use the `default_validators` attribute. [default_validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators).

```
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput, FileField 
from django.core.validators import validate_image_file_extension

class MultipleFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    allow_multiple_selected = True

class MultipleFileField(FileField):
    default_validators = [validate_image_file_extension]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("widget", MultipleFileInput())
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, data, initial=None):
        single_file_clean = super().clean
        if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
            result = [single_file_clean(d, initial) for d in data]
        else:
            result = single_file_clean(data, initial)
        return result
```

Then I use my field, MultipleFileField for my form, something like this `image_of_seller = MultipleFileField()`

I then use `cleaned_data` on MultipleFileField in my form, something like this,

```
def clean(self):
    # other stuff ...
    self.image_of_seller = cleaned_data_get('image_of_seller')
```

Then I use my another model, which has ForeignKey to my User model, and create objects based on the files.

## Example

```py
for file in images:
    ImageSeller.objects.create(
          seller=seller_user,
          image=file,
    )
```

Comment: Now, it's not working, do you have any other solution? See error:[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76797026/form-with-multiple-image-value-return-list-object-has-no-attribute-committed-wh)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment and what I understood, you can achieve this by having your image field as ArrayField in your model:

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    images = models.ArrayField(default=list)
```

then you can make it work in your form like this:

```
class SellerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    images = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), required=False)
```

but you have to handle the data manually in your view:

```
form = SellerForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=seller)
        if form.is_valid():
            seller = form.save(commit=False)
            images = request.FILES.getlist('images')
            for image in images:
                seller.images.append(image)
            seller.save()
```

BUT I would not recommend this approach. The better way is to create another model with ImageField and FK to your main model. then you can use django formsets to handle multiple instances and inlines which you can find many examples, this is from the main doc:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: I found a solution for it, which works for me. I get an error when I try to do, ```images = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), required=False)```, ```ValueError: ClearableFileInput doesn't support uploading multiple files.```, are you sure you can pass this in?

Comment: @SimonBakken-Jantasuk then Try this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

Comment: @scaryhamid I have the same error sir, can you please show us how to use the doc you provided. see the errors I'm facing [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76797026/form-with-multiple-image-value-return-list-object-has-no-attribute-committed-wh)