# form with multiple image value return list object has no attribute _committed when I try to submit it

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a form inside my `forms.py` file when I try to submit the form it throws me an error: `'list' object has no attribute '_committed'`. In that form, I want to allow user to upload multiple image in one model field, for that I have to [follow this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files), but I don't have an idea why it's throws the error every time I try to submit it.

````
model
class LevelType(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.FileField(upload_to='images-level')
    ```
    ```
    ```
````

```
forms.py
class MultipleFileInput(forms.ClearableFileInput):
    allow_multiple_selected = True


class MultipleFileField(forms.FileField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("widget", MultipleFileInput())
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, data, initial=None):
        single_file_clean = super().clean
        if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
            result = [single_file_clean(d, initial) for d in data]
        else:
            result = single_file_clean(data, initial)
        return result

class LevelTypesForms(forms.ModelForm):
    images = MultipleFileField()
    class Meta:
        model = LevelType
        fields = [
            'level', 'bank_name', 'account_number',
            'account_name', 'images', 'price', 'currency',
            'description', 'accept_payment_with_card',
        ]
```

```
   views.py:
class CreateLevelType(CreateView):
    model = LevelType
    form_class = LevelTypesForms
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Level-Types')
    template_name = 'Account/create_level_type.html'

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['level'].queryset = Level.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return form
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()

        images = form.cleaned_data["images"]
        for image in images:
            LevelType.objects.create(
                user=self.request.user,
                image=image
            )
            return redirect('Level-Types')
        return super(CreateLevelType, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error caused by how you handle uploading the image in your forms

first in your forms you need to edit `images` field to be like that

```
class LevelTypesForms(forms.ModelForm):
    images = MultipleFileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = LevelType
        fields = [
            'level', 'bank_name', 'account_number',
            'account_name', 'images', 'price', 'currency',
            'description', 'accept_payment_with_card',
        ]
```

And because you already have a `LevelType` which allows a multiple images in single field you didn't need the loop in your views
So your `form_valid` should be like this :

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.save()
    return redirect('Level-Types')
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer this question, the method that you want me to use is throwing an error: `ClearableFileInput doesn't support uploading multiple files.`